# display result of model.find in view rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a method in my controller which takes a comma separated string as input and displays all the rows which have that particular id.
Input : 1,2,3
Output : All the questions with question id 1 , 2 and 3
Following is the code:

```
@string = params[:question][:question]
if(@string)
 @q_ids=@string.split(",")
 @questions = Question.find(@q_ids)

 format.json { render :search_by_id }
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html {redirect_to search_result_url}
 end
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to search_by_id_url}
  end
end
```

But the output is always :

```
[#,#,#]
```

Please tell me how to display all the fields of the object in the view.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please post your views?

Comment: Following is the view:
    <p>
    The questions matching the string are: <br>
    <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <%= question.question %>
    <br>
    <% end %>
    </p>

Answer (score 0):

In controller, replace `@questions = Question.find(@q_ids)` with

```
@questions = Question.where(id: @q_ids)
```

In view

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
  <%= question.field_name %>
<% end %>
```

where `field_name` should be replaced with appropriate attribute name

Comment: I did the same thing but it gives an error :
      undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use redirect_to if you want show result of @questions?

Try:

```
@q_ids = params[:question][:question].split(",")
@questions = Question.find(@q_ids)

 respond_to do |format|
   # format.json can replace to respond_to block
   format.json { render :search_by_id }
   format.html {render search_result_url}
 end
```

Comment: It is giving the following error : 
    Template is missing


    Missing template http://127.0.0.1:3000/search_result with {:locale=>
    [:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw,
 
:ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates"